# What is the value of length D -Triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

How can I get D?  I know that the triangle right has the measure $1, 1, \sqrt2-1$.
But how can i find out the other?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The hypotenuse of the larger right triangle is $\sqrt{2}$, so the length of the base is $1$. That leaves $\sqrt{2} - 1$ as the base of the smaller triangle.

Now notice that the angle opposed to d is $\frac{\pi}{4}$, because the lengths of the opposite and adjacent sides of the larger triangle are the same.

Answer (score 0):

HINT : The two right triangles at the bottom are the *isosceles right* triangles (why?).